# Link errors using <filesystem> members in C++17

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, std-filesystem

I'm using gcc 7.2 on Ubuntu 16.04, and I need to use the new filesystem library from C++17. Even though there is indeed a library called experimental/filesystem, I can't use any of its members. For example, when I try to compile this file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem::v1;

int main(){
    fs::path p1 = "/usr/share/";
}
```

I get a compilation error which looks like this:

```
$ g++-7 test.cpp -std=c++17
/tmp/ccfsMnlG.o: In function `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::path<char [12], std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path>(char const (&) [12])':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v17__cxx114pathC2IA12_cS3_EERKT_[_ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v17__cxx114pathC5IA12_cS3_EERKT_]+0x73): undefined reference to `st
d::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't think there's anything wrong with the code, since I just copy-pasted it from a website. Am I using the wrong version of gcc? Also, why do I need `<experimental/filesystem>` instead of just `<filesystem>` in C++17? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: I would recommend using some *external* library like [Boost](http://boost.org/) or [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io), or more simply use POSIX calls like [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), notably [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the first link you are pointing to doesn't mention anything about file system support in GCC. In fact, I get zero matches when I search for the string "file".

Comment: This is because you need to check the page about the libstdc++, not g++ itself. It details that support for `<filesystem>` is scheduled to land with g++ 8: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the flag `-lstdc++fs`:

```
$ g++-7 test.cpp -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs
```

gcc 7.2 supports C++17 experimental `filesystem` namespace only. I do not know, maybe gcc 7.3 supports std `filesystem` namespace already.

Comment: I have gcc 7.3 on Arch Linux and I still get the linker error, even with -lstdc++fs.

Comment: I have gcc 8.2 which is meant to support <filesytem>. I have tried adding the flag and the beggining of my compiler output looks like this:   

g++ -c -pipe -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..   Still all function calls are apparently undefined... Any thought?

Comment: @IronAttorney Please copy and paste the compiler error messages.

Comment: `-lstdc++fs` has to go after your .cpp files in the command-line.  If using `make`, add it to your `LDLIBS` variable.

Comment: What happens if I add I compile the same program with gcc 8 though? Would it be able to access experimental/filesystem?

Comment: @SashankAryal You do not need the `-lstdc++fs` flag for GCC 8, it now implements `<filesystem>` with the `-std=c++17` flag.

Comment: I know that, but my question is can Gcc 8 compile <experimental/filesystem> header since it has <filesystem> instead>

Comment: @SashankAryal Sorry. No, `experimental/` prefix must be removed.As I said GCC 8 now implements <filesystem>.

Comment: But when I write library code I do not know what compiler will be used to compile it, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @SashankAryal You can use the macro GCC_VERSION, it and other are described in the GCC manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score 9):

You can also `sudo apt install g++-8` and use `#include <filesystem>` as cppreference described instead of `#include <experimental/filesystem>` in older g++ and libstdc++ version.

> If I install gcc 8 in Ubuntu, will I have 2 different libstdc++ library or merely the original one get updated?
>
> you'll probably have two even though the newer one should work as a drop-in replacement for the old one.

I notice that a `libstdc++-8-dev` is installed along with `g++-8`.

This works for me:

`g++-8 -g -Wall -std=c++17 test.cpp -lstdc++fs`

It seems that even with g++-8, the filesystem library is not automatically linked, you still need to provide `-lstdc++fs`, and `-std=c++17` is also needed in language level.

Answer (score 3):

Following worked for me:

In code:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace filesystem = std::filesystem;
```

In CMakeLists:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lstdc++fs -std=c++17")
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 with GCC 10.

Answer (score 0):

One not-yet-mentioned essential that eluded me for a few hours was in the default CMakeLists.txt:

target_compile_features(compare_files PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
needs to instead be:
target_compile_features(compare_files PUBLIC cxx_std_17)